# Transfer json files from Databricks via SFTP

Tags: databricks, sftp, azure-databricks

We need to transfer multiple JSON files from DBX (e.g. abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1/json_files) ***via SFTP***.

Is there any sample code/notebook with guidelines which we can follow for this task?

- Added this jar in cluster library - **com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3**
- Cluster runtime - **13.1 (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12)**

Tired below code:

```
df.write.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").\
  option("host", hostname).\
  option("username", "user").\
  option("password", "password").\
  option("fileType", "json").\
  save("/ftp/files/sample.json")
```

And getting this error:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Spark File Transfer Library` to transfer the files.
`com.github.arcizon:spark-filetransfer_2.12:0.3.0` for `scala 2.12`
First, install this library in your cluster.

[image]

Using this library you can read and write dataframe in different file formats.
Below is the example of reading a text file.

```
df_txt = spark.read \
    .format("filetransfer") \
    .option("protocol", "sftp") \
    .option("host", host) \
    .option("port", "22") \
    .option("username", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("fileFormat", "text") \
    .load("/pub/example/readme.txt")
    
display(df_txt)
```

[image]

Similarly, you can write data to `sftp` as below.

```
df = spark.read.json(adls_path)

df.write \
    .format("filetransfer") \
    .option("protocol", "sftp") \
    .option("host", host) \
    .option("port", "22") \
    .option("username", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("fileFormat", "json") \
    .save("data/upload/output/sample.json")
```

For more information refer [this](https://github.com/arcizon/spark-filetransfer) GitHub repo.

Comment: This code worked perfect and I have accepted answer. One followup qn, how to transfer large data? e.g. if my Dataframe holds 100 GB of data storing that in one file would not be good option as JSON file might get corrupt. How to divide it in small files?

Comment: As you know spark is multi core architecture load the dataframe and do partitions based on executor memeory. While saving, it will saved according to the partitions with more number of files.

Comment: Using df.write.partitionBy(num) I am able to write in multiple files. we need to give path till folder name only and not to specify file name e.g. .save("data/upload/output/")

Comment: Yes. Give remote folder path.